# Approximate an exponential function

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I have an optimization problem, where I would like to minimize
$$F=\exp(\mathrm{trace}(A)+\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{trace}(A^2)-\lambda)$$
where $A$ is a non-negative matrix.

Is it possible to replace $F$ with $G=\mathrm{trace}(A)+\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{trace}(A^2)-\lambda$ and minimizes $G$ instead of $F$?

Answer (score 0):

Since $\exp$ is an increasing function, yes, $F$ and $G$ have the same minimizers.

See also my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/647835/why-does-finding-the-x-that-maximizes-lnfx-is-the-same-as-finding-the/647842#647842).

Comment: This is true when $\mathrm{trace}(A)+\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{trace}(A^2)-\lambda$ is always positive. But what about when it is negative, Still is valid the replacement?

Comment: @Neshat: Look at the graph of $\exp$. Is it not increasing on the negative axis? It is! So yes, the replacement is still valid.